# Random Distribution between urns

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, balls-in-bins

A simple question.

For 1 million balls scattered in 1 million urns, what fraction of urns have 0 balls, 1 ball, 2 balls, etc.

I tried to solve this but my probability theory knowledge is just basic.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Linearity of Expectation should help here.

Comment: One option is to start with  distributing 3 balls on 3 uns. Tell us at which step you have problems.

Comment: I am trying your suggestion but I am finding even that hard. 
There are 3x3 possible scatters only 1 of which results in 3 balls in a particular urn. So I think 1/9 of urns have 3 balls. 
There are 2 scatters that result in 2 balls in a particular urn. So 2/9 of urns have 2 balls.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: lulu - How can Linearity of Expectation help here?